# Parameterize object names in R

Tags: r, time-series

I need to apply some Time Series models (developed using the "forecast" library of R) to different set of rows in my dataset.

The groups of rows are defined by an ordinal variable called INDEX, ranging from 1 to 10. I'd like to store the results of the models (i.e. forecasts and accuracy metrics) in different objects: the name of these objects should include the INDEX as a suffix.

Here below an example of the code that I need to replicate for each group.. of course I can just copy and paste the section, changing the name of the objects, but I know there should be a wittier solution. I tried with a for loop, but unsuccessfully.

```
ts_1 <- dataset[index=1,]
ts_1 <- ts(ts_1$y, frequency=12)

n_1 <-length(ts_1)

train_1 <-ts(ts_1[1:(n_1-12)], frequency=12)
test_1 <- ts_1[(n_1-(12-1)):n_1]

for_1 <- forecast(train_1, model=arima, h=12)
acc_1 <- accuracy(for_1, test_1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assign` to create objects in your global environment. For example, to create a `ts_*` object for each index 1-10 in your data, you could write the following loop.

```
for(i in 1:10){
  assign(paste0("ts_", i), dataset[index == i, ])
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the `assign` function. I tried to implement your code and it works fine to create the 10 data frames corresponding to each set of rows. But after that, how to refer dynamically to each `ts_*` object? For instance, how to create the objects `n_* <-length(ts_*)` in the `for` loop? I tried with `ts_[i]`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Ok finally I managed to do it using `get()`.. it works, but it seems a bit over complicated to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here the code: 
`for(i in 1:10) {
assign(paste0("ts_", i), na.omit(dataset[index == i,]))
assign(paste0("ts_", i), ts(get(paste0("ts_", i))$y, frequency=12))
assign(paste0("n_", i), length(get(paste0("ts_", i))))

assign(paste0("train_", i), ts(get(paste0("ts_", i))[1:(get(paste0("n_", i))-12)], frequency=12))
assign(paste0("test_", i), get(paste0("ts_", i))[(get(paste0("n_", i))-11):(get(paste0("n_", i)))])

assign(paste0("for_", i), forecast(get(paste0("train_", i)), model=arima, h=12))
assign(paste0("acc_", i), accuracy(get(paste0("for_", i)), get(paste0("test_", i))))
}`

Comment: Yes, if you feel committed to these objects being separate objects in your environment this is what you need to do. You can also save these objects as separate elements of a list, in which case your referencing would be a lot simpler. If this answer solved you problem please accept it by clicking the green check mark!